# Modular help message with python argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using python argparse to manage commandline options. When the number of options becomes large, the help message (what argparse prints when you pass `--help`) is getting intimidating and hard to read, simply because it is to long. Other programs sometimes solve this issue by modularizing the help message: they only show "core options" with `--help` and have options like `--help-modulea`, `--help-moduleb`, etc.

I think that argparse allows for something similar in the presence of subcommands, essentially like git does: `./script.py command --help`.
My application however has no such thing as subcommands, only a big set of options (that can be grouped nicely, though).

Is there any (reasonable) way to do this with argparse?

Comment: You may just be looking for [argument groups](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argument-groups), though they don't help with *suppressing* some of the output. For that, you'll need to define your own option handlers.

Comment: I'm already using argument groups to group the arguments. (obviously) I'm not sure what you mean by "option handlers", though...

Comment: Look at the code for `print_help` and `format_help`.  You'll see how the `HelpFormatter` is called, and how the groups are passed to it.  Also look at the `_help_action` class (or some such name).  I can imagine creating similar Action subclasses and/or formatters that display a subset of your `argument_groups`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @hpaulj answer, I had a proper look at the `argparse` internals and came up with the following. While it has some caveats, I feel it's a good start:

```
class ModularHelpEnabler(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string = None):
        parser.enable_modular_help(self.const)

class ModularArgumentParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._modular_action_groups = {}
        modular_help_groups = kwargs.pop('modular_help_groups', [])
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._modular_help_groups = {}
        for name in modular_help_groups:
            self._modular_help_groups[name] = self.add_argument_group(name)

    def add_argument_group(self, *args, **kwargs):
        name = kwargs.pop('help_name', None)
        help_group = kwargs.pop('help_group', None)
        help_text = kwargs.pop('help_group', 'show help for {}')
        grp = super().add_argument_group(*args, **kwargs)
        if name is not None:
            self._modular_action_groups[grp] = name
            parser = self
            if help_group is not None:
                parser = self._modular_help_groups[help_group]
            parser.add_argument('--help-{}'.format(name), action=ModularHelpEnabler, nargs=0, const=grp, help = help_text.format(name))
        return grp
    def enable_modular_help(self, grp):
        del self._modular_action_groups[grp]
    def format_help(self):
        self._action_groups = [
            ag for ag in self._action_groups
            if ag not in self._modular_action_groups
        ]
        return super().format_help()
```

Caveats (that are not trivial to fix, AFAIK):

- `--help-foo` does not imply `--help`.
- `--help-foo` needs to be given **before** `--help`.

Unfortunately, `--help` directly triggers printing the help and exits. If we retain this behavior, everything that modifies the help message needs to be specified before `--help` itself.
We could defer printing the help until after parsing has finished, however this would mean that `--help` no longer shadows parsing errors (as it does right now), changing the current behavior significantly.